# Email open pixel handler fails in G-Mail

Tags: exm

We are running Sitecore 8.2 and EXM 3.4 on it.

I just noticed that If I open the email in the web G-Mail client, all image urls are being replaced by google with some proxy.

For example the initial html for pixels that we send look like this:
[image]

in G-Mail they all start with `https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/`

[image]

And it appears that first one - email open pixel with G-Mail proxy'ed url returns 404 by some reason - so in the mailbox I see next picture:
[image]

Which also can affect the open email stats in the backend...
Is there anything we can do about it? Is it a known issue?

Comment: This is not an EXM issue, Google has been proxying images for a long time now. See [here](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2013/12/images-now-showing.html), [here](https://blog.filippo.io/how-the-new-gmail-image-proxy-works-and-what-this-means-for-you/) or [here](https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-adds-image-caching-what-you-need-to-know)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, this isn't an EXM issue.

Google has provided an image cacher proxy for emails. The pixel doesn't return a proper image which makes Google think it's broken, but the fact the request was made means that you capture the open still.

It's been a while since I looked at 3.4, but I confirm in Sitecore 9.0.1+ that EXM Open Pixels work just fine in Gmail.

I will agree with you though that it looks weird in Gmail.